# Incompatibility between two WordPress plugins

Tags: wordpress

So I have WPML and Seamless Sticky Custom Post Types. Seamless Sticky Custom Post Types worked fine for custom post types till I installed WPML. Now it doesn't work for custom post types. It works only for normal posts. What should I do to resolve this problem?

**My WPML version is 2.5.2.**

**Seamless Sticky Custom Post Types version is 1.3**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'll answer my own question. Maybe this will help someone else.

After some reading I've come to the first and final conclusion: those to versions from my question are not compatible. I don't really know why(I would like to know). The solution: use WPML version 3.2 or higher and sticky will work with WPML.